# Tables with Fixed Headers vertical scroll bar is Flickr in IE11

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

I am using Table with Fix header (Table TH is fixed) so many column in table. 
but Vertical scroll flickering after scroll horizontal scrollbar in only IE11.
Ex:
https://codepen.io/springborg/pen/MvPmPP

`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th><th>foo</th>
  </thead>
</table>

<div class="pane-vScroll">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td><td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>6</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>7</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>8</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>9</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>10</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>11</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>12</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>13</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>14</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>15</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>16</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>17</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>18</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>19</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>20</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>21</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>22</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>23</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>24</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>25</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>26</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>27</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>28</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>29</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
      <tr><td>30</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfLP2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to the CodePen site, as it said [in the popup modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3gfE.png), "CodePen probably won't work great ".

Based on your code, I create a sample and test it on my local site (using IE11), it seems that everything works well, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Replay,
i am already try to this solution on my local but after click horizontal scrollbar right side arrow vertical scroll bar is Flickring.I am Using IE 11 V- 11.1029.16299.0